# Why does the Unit circle have a radius of 1

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Why is the radius of a unit circle 1? Why can't it be any other number like 10 or 50?

Comment: Circles can have any radius you want. But the one with radius $1$ is special, since then many of the formulas involving $r$ become simpler and less arbitrary than if $r$ were other numbers. So it makes sense to call the circle with radius $1$ something. Since $1$ is unity, we call it the unit circle.

Comment: The unit circle has the radius one (one unit) for a similar reason to the following facts: (1) The one dollar note hs the value of one dollar. (2) The unity has the general sense of the "one". (3) United has the sense of putting many things in a unit. (4) The way we draw circles is by knowing their radius, in an ideal setting.

Comment: [Unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) and [unit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unit#Etymology) : "oneness, singularity".

Comment: The *unit circle* is a circle characterized by the fact that its radius is $1$. Circles that have another radius are not *unit* circles.

Comment: I define the "unit circle" to be a circle of radius 1. That is why the unit circle has radius exactly 1. I could define a "turnip circle" to be a circle of radius 3.14, in which case all turnip circles must have a radius of exactly 3.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a definition of a word. The specific term "unit circle" is *defined* to mean the circle with radius 1.

Why might we want such a word? Well, for one thing, the unit circle can be considered as an instrument to define radian measure: the radian measure of an angle can be described as the arc length of the piece cut out of the unit circle when you draw that angle with its vertex at the center and its rays suitably extended to pass through the circle's circumference. For another, because all circles are similar, any other circle can be described as a rescaling of the unit circle, and the rescaling factor required is equal to the radius of the circle we are describing.

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition of the word "unit". "Unit" means "one/single/individual". Hence by definition, "unit circle" is taken to mean "a circle of radius $1$".

So there's nothing deep going on mathematically; it's just a matter of how we use our English words/a manner of speaking.

---

A similar question is "why do pentagons have $5$ sides"? Well, the answer is just "by definition", because in English, the prefix "pent/penta" means "five". Hence, we use "pentagon" to refer to a figure with $5$ sides.